# Install mongodb in ubuntu 16.4 but failled in the first step

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, makefile, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

Log and error:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-enterprise
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mongodb-enterprise is already the newest version (3.4.9).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up ubuntu-make (17.03~xenial1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-make.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-make.postinst: register-python-argcomplete3: not found
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-make (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-make
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The error is `register-python-argcomplete3: not found`.

Comment: Duplicate on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/836180/dpkg-error-processing-package-ubuntu-make-configure/836182